# Python TensorFlow module not showing up on a Windows 7 machine despite it showing up via “conda list.”

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using minconda and have python 3.7 installed on a Windows 7 machine. I was instructed to use the following commands at the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda create --name=IntroToTensorFlow python=3 anaconda
source activate IntroToTensorFlow
```

Windows did not recognize the word `source`, but did  accept the command when I removed the word `source`

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

the system responds to the last command:

```
(IntroToTensorFlow) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Solving environment: done

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==

current version: 4.5.11

latest version: 4.5.12

Please update conda by running

$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

I updated conda using the above command. There is a hello world program that is suggested to run in a jupyter notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Create TensorFlow object called tensor
hello_constant = tf.constant('Hello World!')
with tf.Session() as sess:
# Run the tf.constant operation in the session
output = sess.run(hello_constant)
print(output)
```

The error is as follows:

> ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  ----> 1 import tensorflow as tf 2 3 # Create TensorFlow object called tensor 4 hello_constant = tf.constant('Hello World!') 5 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

When I enter at Anaconda prompt:

```
conda list
```

TensorFlow shows up on the list

I have read something that Python is not supported yet and should roll back to a previous version of Python 3.6.5 with something called brew. Is this still true? The post is 6 months old

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329187/homebrew-rollback-from-python-3-7-to-python-3-6-5-x

```
brew info python 'brew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What is brew and how do I run it? Is there a Windows 7 alternative? It looks like an Apple system command.

Answer (score 1):

> What is brew and how do I run it? Is there a Windows 7 alternative? It looks like an Apple system command.

`brew` is part of the macOS Homebrew package manager and isn't applicable to Windows 7.

**Tensorflow Python Version Support**

Regarding Python version support, this [Tensorflow GitHub issues thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517) seems to indicate that support for Python 3.7.x (the default Python 3 for current versions of Anaconda, as I understand it) may only be available if you compile Tensorflow yourself (i.e. not through Anaconda).

**Creating A Python 3.6 Environment In Anaconda**

According to the official Anaconda documentation, you may wish to try:

```
conda create -n IntroToTensorFlow python=3.6 anaconda
```

To create a new environment with Python 3.6 (rather than simply `python=3`). Once the environment is activated with e.g.:

```
activate IntroToTensorFlow
```

you should be able to confirm your Python version with:

```
python --version
```

Note that you may need to `deactivate` your existing environment (and remove it as necessary) with e.g.:

```
deactivate
conda remove --name IntroToTensorFlow --all
```

You can verify the availability of a specific environment with:

```
conda info --envs
```

(Taken from the Anaconda documentation on [Managing Environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)).